# Android AsyncTask HttpPost Connection Refused

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

There are so many posts related to this issue and yet I could not find any answer in any of them.... In any case here is my code for the whole activity and the manifest:

My local IP is currently 192.168.1.3, and I get Connection Refused to 192.168.1.3 But I've tried to access it from the browser in my PC and in my phone and the local server is working fine.

```
package com.cablin.cablinmobile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public  static String LoginUrl = "http://192.168.1.3/tspmetodologiaserver/public/mobileauth";

    public EditText editTextUsername;
    public EditText editTextPassword;
    public TextView textViewMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        textViewMessage = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public void login(View view) {

        new LoginAsyncTask().execute();

        /*

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPerViewListActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(MessageName, "Something");

        this.startActivity(intent);

        */


    }

    private class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String result = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(LoginUrl);

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", editTextUsername.getText().toString()));
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", editTextPassword.getText().toString()));

            InputStream in = null;

            try {

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

                in = httpEntity.getContent();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    stringBuilder.append(line);

                }

                result = stringBuilder.toString();



            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                try {

                    if(in != null) in.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            try {

              if(result != null) {
                  jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
              }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(jsonObject != null)
                textViewMessage.setText(jsonObject.toString());
            else
                textViewMessage.setText("JSON NULL");

        }

    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cablin.cablinmobile" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

        <activity
            android:name="com.cablin.cablinmobile.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.cablin.cablinmobile.PayPerViewListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pay_per_view_list" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

HERE IS MY ERROR:

```
11-23 20:10:30.626    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile I/System.out﹕ AsyncTask #4 calls detatch()
11-23 20:10:30.626    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.3 refused
11-23 20:10:30.626    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:212)
11-23 20:10:30.626    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
11-23 20:10:30.626    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
11-23 20:10:30.626    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1179)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:644)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at com.cablin.cablinmobile.MainActivity$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:120)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at com.cablin.cablinmobile.MainActivity$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:96)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:210)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:576)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:664)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:808)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:561)
11-23 20:10:30.631    3373-4336/com.cablin.cablinmobile W/System.err﹕ ... 20 more
```

Comment: I've also tried using Postman to check the route and it works

Comment: I haven't gone through your code but are you using wifi? Sometimes basic things got missed out.

Comment: yes, I'm on wifi, my cellphone is connected to my home network right now

Comment: I added the error message from the logcat

Comment: I tried changing the URL to http://www.google.com and now I get Permission Denied, missing Internet Permission? .... but I clearly put the uses-permission in the manifest .. o.O

Comment: Maybe a clean is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "uses-permission" should be outside the "application"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

I would also suggest adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

So you can verify yhat the device has Network connectivity

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            {
                ...
            }
```